# PHP string concatenation mess

Tags: php

Can anyone help me fix this php string mess?

```php
echo '<nav class="navEl"><a href="' . $route . '" '.($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' . $route) ? 'style="color:' . $currentPathColor . '"' : '' . '>' . $route . '</a></nav>';
```

This is whats supposed to do(this works):

```php
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' . $route) {
    echo '<nav class="navEl"><a href="' . $route . '" style="color:' . $currentPathColor . '">' . $route . '</a></nav>';
} else {
    echo '<nav class="navEl"><a href="' . $route . '">' . $route . '</a></nav>';
}
```

Just practicing PHP for the purpose of knowing something about it, thanks in advance!

Comment: Think of the poor guy a year in the future who has to maintain this. If you can't get it to work now, he's going to have a bad day changing it. Clever code is all very well, but I'll go for maintainable code every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can understand wanting to reduce repetition of code, and as such I would suggest putting the common html in two separate parts with an `if` in the middle.  This achieves the same as you are trying to get but with (IMHO) a more maintainable structure...

```
echo '<nav class="navEl"><a href="' . $route;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' . $route) {
    echo '" style="color:' . $currentPathColor;
} 
echo  '">' . $route . '</a></nav>';
```

( I have not tested this, so can't 100% guarantee the quotes are correct, but I hope you get the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

As PHP is a template engine, you can make use of it and maintain readability.

```
$style = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === "/$route") ? "style='color:$currentPathColor'" : '';

echo <<<_HTML
<nav class="navEl"><a href="$route" $style>$route</a></nav>
_HTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have given some reasonable alternative styles, but to address the immediate problem, your issue is one of [operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

In order of precedence, you have:

1. A parenthesised expression
2. The `.` concatenation operator
3. The ternary `?:` operator

So PHP evaluates things a bit like this:

```php
// Parentheses
$boolean = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' . $route;
// Concatenation
$string_1 = '<nav class="navEl"><a href="' . $route . '" '. $boolean;
$string_2 = 'style="color:' . $currentPathColor . '"';
$string_3 = '' . '>' . $route . '</a></nav>';
// Ternary
$chosen_string = $string_1 ? $string_2 : $string_3;
// echo
echo $chosen_string;
```

But what you wanted was this:

```php
// String sections
$prefix = '<nav class="navEl"><a href="' . $route . '" ';
$suffix_a = 'style="color:' . $currentPathColor . '"';
$suffix_b = '' . '>' . $route . '</a></nav>';
// Condition
$condition = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' . $route;
// Ternary
$chosen_suffix = $condition ? $suffix_a : $suffix_b;
// Combine
$string = $prefix . $chosen_suffix;
// echo
echo $string;
```

So as well as parentheses around the condition, you want parentheses around the whole "suffix" section, so that that gets evaluated first:

```php
echo
    '<nav class="navEl"><a href="' . $route . '" '
    .
    (
        ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' . $route )
        ?
        'style="color:' . $currentPathColor . '"'
        :
        '' . '>' . $route . '</a></nav>'
    );
```

Since this kind of mistake is so easy to make, and the result easy to misinterpret, it's generally a good idea to simply avoid complex expressions like this, and introduce intermediate variables, use `if` statements, and so on.